# getting error while kept react-native-material-dropdown inside flatlist

Tags: reactjs

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this._scrollRef.scrollTo(this.props.horizontal ? { x: offset, animated: animated } : { y: offset, animated: animated })')
scrollToOffset
    index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:46356:31
scrollToOffset
    index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:44939:35
resetScrollOffset
    index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:96005:35
```

Comment: Can you add your code? add description to the problem.

Comment: Please inform yourself about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <FlatList
          scrollToOffset={{animated:true}}
          horizontal={false}
            data={this.state.products}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
               <View style={styles.dropDownCss}>
                <Dropdown
                dropdownOffset={{top:5,left:10,position:'absolute'}}
                   containerStyle={{
                   }}
                   inputContainerStyle={styles.dropDownTextCss}
                   data={dr[index]}
                   value={dr[index][0].value}
                 />